# Controlling the API calls in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In jmeter i am executing 5 api , i am using ultimate thread group in which my requirements is each api need to hit 500 samples. But in my case first 2 api hits maximum number than the others and the remaining apis in minimum hits.

Is there any way to execute eventually

My ultimate thread group configuration [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot control how many requests will be executed exactly using Ultimate Thread Group only because this way you can control only the **number of users**, the number of hits depends on your system response time. See [How do I Correlate the Number of (Concurrent) Users with Hits Per Second](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420695-How-do-I-Correlate-the-Number-of-Concurrent-Users-with-Hits-Per-Second) article for more information.

You can go for one of the following options:

1. Artificially limit the number of executions for each sampler using [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)
2. Artificially limit the rate of executions using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) and [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) combination